# Error in lmer: (p <- ncol(X)) == ncol(Y) is not TRUE

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to fit a model with a     lmer     and I keep getting the error:

```
Error : (p <- ncol(X)) == ncol(Y) is not TRUE
```

The model is the following:

```
model.covars.im.adapt <- lmer (data$im.adpt ~ data$pnr + data$female_c + data$age_c + data$age_c2 + (1 | data$nomem_encr) +  (1 | data$nohouse_encr))
```

This problem may be due to NAs, because the following model, in which the dependent variable has no NAs, runs well:

```
model.covars.rw <- lmer (data$rw ~ data$pnr + data$female_c + data$age_c + data$age_c2 + (1 | data$nomem_encr) +  (1 | data$nohouse_encr))
```

However, when I code to exclude the NAs, I keep getting the same error:

```
data <- data[-is.na(data$im.adpt), ]
model.covars.con <- lmer (data$im.adpt ~ data$pnr + data$female_c + data$age_c + data$age_c2 + (1 | data$nomem_encr) +  (1 | data$nohouse_encr))
```

Here is a summary of data$rw:

```
       V1           
 Min.   :-2.431773  
 1st Qu.:-0.574774  
 Median :-0.110525  
 Mean   : 0.000063  
 3rd Qu.: 0.817975  
 Max.   : 2.210723
```

And a summary of data$im.adpt:

```
      V1          
 Min.   :-2.75092  
 1st Qu.:-0.69883  
 Median : 0.32721  
 Mean   :-0.00002  
 3rd Qu.: 0.32721  
 Max.   : 1.35326  
 NA's   :316
```

What do you recommend? I am capable of providing more relevant information.

Comment: You are using the model formula wrong.A shorter example would be something like `lmer(im.adpt ~ pnr + female_c + (1 | nomem_encr), data = data)`